# Probability of hitting empty bottles

Tags: probability

The cartridge chamber of my gun can carry $n$ bullets but it is loaded randomly with only $b$ bullets. There are $n$ bottles and $v$ of them are full and $n-v$ are empty.

Now I try to shoot at every bottle from 1 to $n$. A bottle breaks if and only if it is hit by a bullet. Consider that I am a perfect shooter and never miss a bottle if I shoot.

What is the probabilty that I only hit empty bottles?

Obviously a necessary condition is that $b \leq n-v$.

Has anyone an Idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you also have a probability of a bullet hitting a bottle, or do you assume that if the bullet leaves the chamber then it will definitely hit a bottle?

Comment: it will definetly hit the bottle. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be rephrased as: "if I randomly select $b$ of the $n$ bottles then what is the probability that they are all empty?"

The answer is:$$\frac{\binom{n-v}b\binom{v}0}{\binom{n}b}=\frac{\binom{n-v}b}{\binom{n}b}$$

Application of hypergeometric distribution.